# Preg_replace error, when using different language text. (Getting rid of lines)

Tags: php, preg-replace, line

I have content like this

```
`மிழர்களி வரறில் யூலை மாதம் என்பது கனத்த மாதமாக பதிவு செய்யப்பட்டுள்ளது.

 குறிபாக ஐந்து ஆண்ளின் யூலை கள் முக்கியமானவை. 1983ம் ஆண்டிற்கு முன்பே 

யூலை மாதம் தமிழர்களுடன் பின்னிப் பிணைந்து`
```

I want to get rid of all the lines so i get something like this.

```
மிழர்களி வரறில் யூலை மாதம் என்பது கனத்த மாதமாக பதிவு செய்யப்பட்டுள்ளது. குறிபாக ஐந்து ஆண்ளின் யூலை கள் முக்கியமானவை. 1983ம் ஆண்டிற்கு முன்பே குறிபாக ஐந்து ஆண்ளின் யூலை கள் முக்கியமானவை. 1983ம் ஆண்டிற்கு முன்பே
```

I am using this code `preg_replace("/\n+||\r+/"," ", $content);` but the problem is that I my output is:

`� � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � �`

I have also tried mb_ereg_replace but I get the same results.
When i use this `preg_replace("/\n+||\r+/","", $content);` then it is fine but the problem is that I need space inbetween the text, so instead of having a new line I need a space. I have also tried seriallize. 
Thanks you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`preg_replace` works bytewise, unless you pass the `U` flag. And your regular expression is not only replacing newlines with spaces, it is also inserting a space between every byte since it matches the empty string. Which breaks the UTF-8 encoding.

You probably meant to use a regular expression something like `'/[\r\n]+/'` instead.

Comment: Thanks man, this works perfect man your a life saver I was trying to fix this for a long time.